# TestNG/Webdriver/Java - passing parameters via annotations?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am relatively new to Java, TestNG and Selenium Webdriver (3 weeks) and it seems Im not passing parameters correctly, the way TestNG wants me to.

The test runs perfectly, but then it says it failed for the following reason:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The data provider is trying to pass 2 parameters but the method com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppTest2#twoUsersSignUp takes 1
```

Here is my code:

```
public class AppTest2 {
     public WebDriver driver;
     public WebDriverWait wait;

         @DataProvider(name = "dataProvider")
         public Object[][] setUp() throws Exception {
         File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
         FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
         ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":20");
         driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffox, null);
         wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds );
         Object[][] data = new Object[1][2];
         data[0][0] = driver;
         data[0][1] = wait;
         twoUsersSignUp(data);
         return data;
     }

     @Parameters({ "data" })
     @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider")
     public void twoUsersSignUp(@Optional Object[][] data) throws InterruptedException{

           //test here

         }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your test method with the data that you are filling in the dataprovider, so in your case, it should be

```
 public void twoUsersSignUp(WebDriver d, WebDriverWait w).
```